# How to vertically-align scanner input in Java?

Tags: java, printf, java.util.scanner, vertical-alignment

I'm having trouble figuring this out. What am I missing in my code such that my expected result on the terminal looks like this? (first image). I hope to vertically allign the user input ( 10,20,30 ).

I am using the scanner for user input and it prompts for input after a formatted string is displayed on the terminal.

[image]

However, mine looks like this.

[image]

Here is a portion of the code.

```
    System.out.println("Please place your order");
    System.out.println("-----------------------");

    System.out.printf("No. of %s: " , item_1);
    order_QTY_1 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.printf("No. of %s: " , item_2);
    order_QTY_2 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.printf("No. of %s: " , item_3);
    order_QTY_3 = input.nextInt();
```

Thank you so much and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I would just use the standard println() method and not printf, unless you are required to. You could just use sysout( "No, of things:     " ) and hardcode the necessary spaces into it. This would only left align them, if you want them right aligned you'd have to calculate the length of the number being appended and prepend a calculated number of spaces to it. But, at the simplest level, just hardcode additional spaces.

Comment: You're already using %s in your printf statements.  Change it to %-20s, where 20 is the maximum number of characters in an item.  Concatenate the colon with the item.